# Python C API - Using Comparison functions causes 'Segmentation fault'

Tags: python, c, api

I am currently trying to learn about writing Python extensions in C and everything seemed to be going well. However, when I tried using comparison functions, but they all cause Segmentaion fault. for example:

```
#include "Python.h"

int test(void) {
    int result;
    printf("Before compare...\n");
    result = PyObject_Compare(PyInt_FromLong(1), PyInt_FromLong(3));
    printf("result= %d\n", result);
    return 0;   
}
```

executing `test()` from Python (I used ctypes) gives the following output:

```
Before compare...
Segmentation fault
```

This happend with me for the other comparison functions like: `PyObject_cmp`...etc

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

#### more info:

I first compiled the file (test.c) to a shared library:

```
$> python-config --cflags
-I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
$> python-config --ldflags
-L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython2.7 -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions

$> gcc -c $(python-config --cflags) ./test.c -o test.o
$> gcc -shared  ./test.o  $(python-config --ldflags) -o libtest.so
```

then I started the function from Python like this:

```
import ctypes
testlib = ctypes.CDLL('./libtest.so')

testlib.test()
```

#### edit:

Using the test given by Viktor

```
$> gcc -o dlltest test.c -ldl
$> gdb dlltest
(gdb) run
Starting program: dlltest 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Cannot find new threads: generic error
(gdb)
```

so I did this:

```
$> LD_PRELOAD=libpthread-2.13.so gdb dlltest
(gdb) run
Starting program: dlltest
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Before compare...
result= -1
[Inferior 1 (process 3274) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

#### edit 2:

```
>$ gdb --args python frompython.py
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/python frompython.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Before compare...

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080a855b in PyObject_Compare ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x080a855b in PyObject_Compare ()
#1  0x005225d8 in test () at ./testmod.c:29
#2  0x005181ca in ffi_call_SYSV ()
   from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#3  0x00517eff in ffi_call () from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#4  0x00510312 in _ctypes_callproc ()
   from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#5  0x0050788d in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#6  0x0805dc31 in PyObject_Call ()
#7  0x080f81c1 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#8  0x080fd804 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#9  0x080fe177 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#10 0x0811acd0 in ?? ()
#11 0x0811b8e9 in PyRun_FileExFlags ()
#12 0x0811c4cc in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
#13 0x0812c7c6 in Py_Main ()
#14 0x0805da0b in main ()
(gdb)
```

Comment: Provide a minimal, complete example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: How did you initialise python? Are you using multiple threads? Are you checking for errors? Is python still initialised or did you destroy it? Did you attempt to reload the interpreter?  Please show the full, minimal program.

Comment: @Arafangion I tried using a python script, as well as from the interpreter, same problem. But I haven't checked for errors. I don't really know what to check for, sorry I'm still a beginner.

Comment: Why are you using `ctypes` if you're trying to write a C extension?

Comment: I found it easier to start with. I'm not really trying to write an extension, just want to learn how to do it. Is using ctypes wrong like this ?

Comment: Well, yes. `ctypes` is meant for executing non-Python code; I can't imagine anything better than a segfault as a result of trying to run Python code with it.

Comment: I'm executing the C function `test()` with `ctypes`, I didn't execute any Python code with it.

Comment: also other functions from the Python C API worked fine with me.`PyObject_Compare` and it's siblings were the ones which caused me problems.

Comment: Amr: If you're doing it using ctypes (Why the heck!?!?), just be aware that, obviously, python is already instantiated, and that you'll now have to be VERY aware of undocumented implementation details such as how the GIL is held, etc.  Do not use ctypes for interacting with the python API, if you have a python api, then *write python*, if you do not, then consider ctypes, perhaps.

Comment: @Arafangion Of course I am not using C to compare two python integers, I was just trying to make one of my functions in python faster. so I decided to do it in C, but I have to use Python API also because I need to deal with some Python objects. Sorry if I'm not clear or if my terminology is a bit off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no initialization of the Python's interpreter in the 'test()' function (no Py_Initialize call).

PyInt_FromLong() returns a pointer to the internal array, which is uninitialized in your case. So you get some invalid pointer and passing it to the Py_Compare() function crashes the interpreter.

See here for details on intialization:
http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#initializing-and-finalizing-the-interpreter

At least try adding the "Py_Initialize()" call at the beginning of the test() function.

EDIT:

Interesting, what would be the stack trace from GDB if you run the libtest.test from C using this prog:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef int (*fcn)();

int main()
{
    void* dll = dlopen("libtest.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    /* dlerror checks here */

    fcn Test = (fcn)dlsym(dll, "test");

    Test();

    dclose(dll);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT2:

1. Compile the test (gcc -o dlltest test.c -ldl)
2. Run "gdb dlltest"
3. Type the command "run" in gdb prompt
4. See whether it crashes
5. If yes, type the backtrace in gdb's prompt.

EDIT3:

It's not clear where the crash is. Try adding "fflush(stdout);" after each printf() call to be sure that the error is printed.

If the "result= -1" appears in your python-based app, then the error is in ctypes, not in the libtest.so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but using Py_Initialize() didn't make a difference. I'll have to try without ctypes as others have suggested.

Comment: Can you please add the outputs of "python-config --ldflags" and "python-config --cflags" ?

Comment: I added them in the question.

Comment: Thanks. Added the C test. Maybe you try it and dump the GDB's output to get why is it crashing ?

Comment: Thanks again, I'm really still a beginner and debugging stuff with gdb is out of the question for me right now. However, I tried running your C test but it didn't work at the beginning, after searching for a while I used `-lpthread` with gcc for my shared library (have no idea why) and then your test program worked with it, but python with ctypes still gave the same behaviour.

Comment: So, test.c (let's call it this way) works and does not crash ? Then it looks like python's 'ctypes' load the .so file in some incorrect way... I'm interested in python myself, so the utility of this question is mutual.

Comment: Added suggestion (edit3) - try flushing the stdout, the crash might "eat" the actual "result= -1" output.

Comment: using `fflush(stdout);` after `printf` didn't make a difference with Python and ctypes, "result= -1" still didn't appear.

Comment: At least it shows that the PyCompare does not get called. Try the last resort  - debug the python interpreter. Run "gdb --args python yoursamplewithctypes.py" and see what the output is. I mean the "backtrace" after the crash.

Comment: I'll try learning ways other than ctypes and see if they work out, thanks for your help.

Comment: yes, it seems the problem is after all within `PyObject_Compare` when using ctypes, see my last edit.

Comment: Glad that we've partially resolved it. Good luck with non-ctypes solution :)